# How to limit unreadNotifications in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

the code below displays all the unread notifications of a logged in user in laravel:

```
auth()->user()->unreadNotifications
```

I put the code into a tag and bind it as unreads property so that my vue component can access the `unreads` data.

```
<notification :userid="{{ auth()->user()->id }}" :unreads="{{ auth()->user()->unreadNotifications }}"></notification>
```

Everything works fine.

From the vue js, I can limit the unreads data to the number results I want.

However, when I view the source code in a browser, I can see the all notifications are displayed, hence, delaying of page load since there are a lot of results on it.

Now, I want to **LIMIT**  `auth()->user()->unreadNotifications` so that I can control the number of results to be displayed. I checked on google and laravel docs, but I found none. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an issue on the Laravel Framework GitHub that suggests you could use:

```
auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->take(10)->get()
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18789